# How to change cursor in css?

Tags: html, css, cursor

I want to change simple cursor to image, so i have this code which isnt working

```
html{
    cursor: url(image/cursor.ico),  auto;
} 
body{
    cursor: url(image/cursor.ico),  auto;
}
*{
    cursor: url(image/cursor.ico),  auto;
}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: does the url actually go somewhere?

Comment: @ZachJensz yes, it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably not with your CSS code (although I recommend double checking the link to your image).

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) says this:

> While the specification does not limit the cursor image size, user agents commonly restrict them to avoid potential misuse. For example, on Firefox and Chromium cursor images are restricted to 128x128 pixels by default, but it is recommended to limit the cursor image size to 32x32 pixels.

I had an image that didn't work, changing the size to 32x32 indeed solved the problem!

Comment: LETS GOOOO IT WORKS WELL, THANKS!!!!!